# Elastic search to find index existis or not using Java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Before am indexing the documents i want to check whether my index name is already existis in the ElasticSearcch or not.

Please find the below piece of code which am using `RestLowLevelClient` to find my index existis.

```
public boolean checkIfIndexExists(String indexName) throws IOException {
        Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest("HEAD", "/" + indexName);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
        return (statusCode != 404);
    }
```

But i want to using `RestHighLevelClient` and how i can modify the same code.

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: @C.Weber - am using ES 6.2.3 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the [Indices Exists API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-indices-exists.html):

```
public boolean checkIfIndexExists(String indexName) throws IOException {
    GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest();
    request.indices(indexName); 
    return client.indices().exists(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is only available since 6.3

Comment: True, I answered before knowing the version, indeed. Then the OP is left with two options: 1) use the low-level client or 2) upgrade

Comment: indexName is now moved to contractor level.
GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest(indexName);